# Why does an iterator lose its content after being printed out?

Tags: python, debugging, runtime-error

When I try to print the contents of an iterator, they disappear. Is this the expected behavior?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
string="foobarbaz" # Only as an example.

characters = string.encode('ISO-8859-1')
iterator = zip(characters[1:], characters)
iteratora = zip(characters[1::2], characters[::2])
iteratorb = zip(characters[2::2], characters[1::2])
# print(list(iterator))
# print(list(iteratora))
# print(list(iteratorb))
elements = [x + 2 * y if index % 2 else x * y
            for index, (x, y) in enumerate(iterator)]
hex((sum(elements) + characters[0]) % 0x10000)
```

The above code behaves as expected and returns the following:

```
'0xac66'
```

Now, I want to uncomment the first print line, so the code will look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

string="foobarbaz" # Only as an example.

characters = string.encode('ISO-8859-1')
iterator = zip(characters[1:], characters)
iteratora = zip(characters[1::2], characters[::2])
iteratorb = zip(characters[2::2], characters[1::2])
print(list(iterator))
# print(list(iteratora))
# print(list(iteratorb))
elements = [x + 2 * y if index % 2 else x * y
            for index, (x, y) in enumerate(iterator)]
hex((sum(elements) + characters[0]) % 0x10000)
```

Now it returns this:

```
'0x66'
```

Is the `list` conversion in the `print` statement altering the original value of `iterator`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list(iterator)` consumes the iterator. Therefore when uncommenting `print(list(iterator))`, `elements` will be an empty list:

```
string = "foobarbaz"
characters = string.encode('ISO-8859-1')
iterator = zip(characters[1:], characters)
print(list(iterator))
# [(111, 102), (111, 111), (98, 111), (97, 98), (114, 97), (98, 114), (97, 98), (122, 97)]

elements = [x + 2 * y if index % 2 else x * y
            for index, (x, y) in enumerate(iterator)]

print(elements)
# []
```

Compared to:

```
string = "foobarbaz"

characters = string.encode('ISO-8859-1')
iterator = zip(characters[1:], characters)
elements = [x + 2 * y if index % 2 else x * y
            for index, (x, y) in enumerate(iterator)]
print(elements)
# [11322, 333, 10878, 293, 11058, 326, 9506, 316]
```

If you want to print `iterator` you should deepcopy it:

```
import copy

.
.
print(list(copy.deepcopy(iterator)))
.
.
```

Another approach would be to turn `iterator` to list before trying to print it:

```
.
.
iterator = list(zip(characters[1:], characters))
print(iterator)
# [(111, 102), (111, 111), (98, 111), (97, 98), (114, 97), (98, 114), (97, 98), (122, 97)]
elements = [x + 2 * y if index % 2 else x * y
            for index, (x, y) in enumerate(iterator)]

print(elements)
# [11322, 333, 10878, 293, 11058, 326, 9506, 316]
```

Comment: Definitely, a huge layer-8 error. I feel a̶ ̶b̶i̶t̶ stupid. I'll skip all the SE rules to say **Thank you!**. Now it seems obvious (after knowing the solution).